# How to restrict ckeditor to display full html alone?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I am using ck editor and want to hide the filtered html and plain text.

And user should use only the full html format. They should not get the option to select filtered html and plain text.

Anyone guide me how to do this in ck editor?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [Better Formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_formats) module to achieve this.

Better formats is a module to add more flexibility to Drupal's core input format system.

> ### Features
>
> 8.x & 7.x (needs more testing for a stable release)
>
> - Set allowed text formats per field.
> - Set default order of text formats per field.
> - Hide format tips per role.
> - Hide more format tips link per role.
> - Hide format selection per role per entity.
> - Currently only works on Field API fields on fieldable entities implementing core - style text processing. The good thing is that is
>     most things in core and contrib.

This will let you limit what format is available per field implementing formatted text, like a body field.

Despite what the warning says, I have used this extensively on many sites to do exactly what you asked about.